# неправильно считывает данные из файлов .txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый вечер еще раз. Программа неправильно считывает данные из файлов .txt. Хочу сразу сказать спасибо ответившему на предыдущий мой вопрос. Привожу часть кода и прошу прощения что уже приводил его сегодня:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std;

double Tnach[139][139][50];
double Temper[139][139][50];
double Temper1[139][139][50];
double Tempernach[139][139][50];
double Tut[139][139];
double Tut1[139][139];
double Tut11[139][139];
double Tut22[139][139];


int main() {
const int i = 0;
```

далее перечислены задействованные переменные. Потом идет считывание из файлов:

```
ifstream fan1;
fan1.open("pov20.txt", ios::in);
ifstream fan2;
fan2.open("nak20.txt", ios::in);
ifstream fan3;
fan3.open("h20.txt", ios::in);
ofstream fout;
fout.open("res1.txt", ofstream::out);

for (int i = 0;i<Lan;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j<Lan;j++) {
        fan1 >> pov[i][j];
        fan2 >> nak[i][j];
        fan3 >> h[i][j];
        ber1 = pov[1][2];
        ber2 = nak[1][2];
        ber3 = h[1][2];
    }
}
```

и при пошаговом прохождении в окне Локальные я вижу что считываются совсем не те значения:например переменная ber1=-9.25+61
В файлах находятся совсем другие значения. Переменные ber1, ber2 и ber3 были специально мною вставлены чтобы проверить какие значения он считывает из файлов. Совсем не те. Поэтому вопрос: он явно не читает то что нужно: почему? И откуда берет то что показывает мне?

Comment: Еще бы посмотреть на содержимое файлов. Да и - считываете-то вы сначала одни данные, а читаете другие. Вы до них точно добрались при проверке? :) Да и потом, вы **не проверяете**, считываются ли данные вообще! может, там уже давно потоки в состоянии `fail`...

Comment: Дело в том, что я перевожу код программы с матлаба (для ускорения расчетов). Там считывается все проще: что есть то и есть. Там я считываю вообще из Excel . Но в с++ считать из Excel еще сложнее чем из txt.  Вы считаете что я не считываю данные из этих файлов?  Вроде я по учебникам онлайн целый день копал.

Comment: Я этого не утверждаю, но проверка никогда не мешает :) - как минимум, позволяя убрать из рассмотрения часть возможных причин. По тому, как описано у вас - определить точно, что именно происходит, сложно. Вы приводите вначале код, не имеющий никакого отношения к делу (все эти массивы - они же не имеют отношения к чтению), потом непонятный отладочный вывод - это, скажем так, далеко не образец, как надо спрашивать :)

Comment: Я приводил список всех подключенных библиотек на всякий случай.  А дальше только как я считывал данные: fstream и т.д.  Там между описаниями переменных и этими операторами ничего нет.

Comment: Вообще ничего? Даже описания массивов pov, nak, h и тому подобного? так ваш код просто не компилируется :) Впрочем, судя по принятому ответу, проблему вы уже решили, так что эта дискуссия теряет смысл...

Comment: Нет, проблема не решена. Массивы pov, nak и h описываются выше как double pov[139][139], double nak[139][139] и double h[139][139]

Comment: Знаете, просто чтоб закрыть вопрос - сложите-ка ваши файлы вместе с txt'шками, упакуйте и положите на каком-то файлообменнике, попробую взглянуть...

Comment: http://fayloobmennik.cloud/7184548 Вот ссылка на файл пароль armavir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цитирую самый первый свой комментарий: *"Еще бы посмотреть на содержимое файлов."*

Они же с запятыми вместо точек! Еще и в юникоде! Там же каждый второй байт - нулевой!

Допишите проверку на корректность ввода:

```
if (!(fan1 >> pov[i][j])) cout << "Error fan1\n";
if (!(fan2 >> nak[i][j])) cout << "Error fan2\n";
if (!(fan3 >> h[i][j]))   cout << "Error fan3\n";
```

и убедитесь, что там вообще ничего не читается!

Словом, чтоб вам не переписывать все для работы с Unicode и локалями - откройте в каком-нибудь Блокноте, замените все запятые на точки и сохраните как ANSI, а не Unicode.

Comment: Точно!!! Вы - гений. Как я задолбался разбираться с потоками и еще с записью fstream для разных версий Visual Studio, а про запятые и не подумал! Счас заменю и попробую.

Comment: Ну что, получилось? Если все нормально - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...

Comment: У меня ответ еще не готов. Запятые на точки я заменил, но обнаружил проблему с путями к файлам. Похоже он вообще их не нашел. А поскольку я еще параллельно занимаюсь одной задачей и сдаю ее сегодня (до полуночи), то я пока эту задачу не довел. Поэтому колеблюсь: закрыть вопрос ( а ну как завтра еще что-нибудь вылезет и я буду тут с повторным вопросом) или закрыть чтобы не тянуть резину а там как получится.

Answer (score 1):

```
ber1 = pov[1][2];
ber2 = nak[1][2];
ber3 = h[1][2];
```

Эти данные считываются в теле цикла, а именно на первой итерации тогда, когда именно эти элементы матрицы еще не заполнены и там хранится "мусор"

Comment: Я поставил эти переменные после цикла и результат один в один как и был: for (int i = 0;i<Lan;i++) {
  for (int j = 0;j<Lan;j++) {
   fan1 >> pov[i][j];
   fan2 >> nak[i][j];
   fan3 >> h[i][j];
   
  }
 }
 ber1 = pov[1][2];
 ber2 = nak[1][2];
 ber3 = h[1][2];